# MongoDB - Cannot recover the transaction decision without a recoveryToken

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, sharding

I am using Mongo Server v4.2. and python3.7, pymongo v3.7.1 to update multiple collections within a transaction in a Sharded setup(2 router, 3 config, 2 Replicaset(1 Primary, 2 secondary)). 
I have written 2 methods to start a transaction and end transaction below

```
def dbTransactionStart(db):

    # Start Session
    session = db.client.start_session()

    # Start Transaction
    #session.start_transaction(write_concern = wcMajority)
    session.start_transaction()

    return session

def dbTransactionEnd(session):

    # Commit Transaction
    session.commit_transaction()

    # End session
    session.end_session()
```

Updating the collections like below

```
# Init DB
mongoClient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://" + MONGO_USERNAME + ":" + urllib.parse.quote_plus(MONGO_PASSWORD) + "@" + MONGO_HOST + "/" + MONGO_DB)
db = mongoClient[MONGO_DB]


# Start Transaction
session = dbTransactionStart(db)

db.collection1.update_one(query, param, session = session)

db.collection2.update_one(query, param, session = session)

db.collection3.update_one(query, param, session = session)

# End Transaction
dbTransactionEnd(session)
```

I am getting the below error saying **Cannot recover the transaction decision without a recoveryToken** during the end transaction. Can anyone help regarding this

```
  File "./libs/util.py", line 167, in dbTransactionEnd
    session.commit_transaction()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/client_session.py", line 393, in commit_transaction
    self._finish_transaction_with_retry("commitTransaction")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/client_session.py", line 457, in _finish_transaction_with_retry
    return self._finish_transaction(command_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/client_session.py", line 452, in _finish_transaction
    parse_write_concern_error=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 514, in _command
    client=self.__client)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 579, in command
    unacknowledged=unacknowledged)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 150, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Cannot recover the transaction decision without a recoveryToken
```

Comment: And the above error is not consistent, which means many times the above code is success and sometimes it throws the above error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with pymongo cliet version v3.7 which I upgrade to v3.10.1 which made it work smoothly